# How it works Magento's observer

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I've a big doubt with Observers in Magento. I can't understand this events in Magento.

```
    <events>
         <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
            <observers>
                <onepagecheckout>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>onepagecheckout/observer</class>
                    <method>removeHistoryComment</method>
                </onepagecheckout>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
            <observers>
                <onepagecheckout>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>onepagecheckout/observer</class>
                    <method>addHistoryComment</method>
                </onepagecheckout>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>

        <controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_cart_index>
            <observers>
                <onepagecheckout>
                    <class>onepagecheckout/observer</class>
                    <method>setEmptyCartTemplate</method>
                </onepagecheckout>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_cart_index>

    </events>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I only want to understand how it works the obsevers

Comment: That is too broad.

Comment: Yes I know, but I need a "click"... I read a lot about observers, but is abstract to me, I don't understand what observers do exactly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php,

- Before the order is save magento dispatch an event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` incase you want save addition info or edit info before the transaction save using a observer.

  Note : If you try to SAVE() within your observer you will get a endless loop
- After the order is save magento dispatch an event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_after` incase do something after all the info is save to the db using a observer.

  Note : You must SAVE() info within your observer

See

```
    /**
     * We can use configuration data for declare new order status
     */
--> Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_type_onepage_save_order', array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quote));
    Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_service_quote_submit_before', array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quote));
    try {
-->     $transaction->save();
        $this->_inactivateQuote();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_service_quote_submit_success', array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quote));
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        ......
    }
--> Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_service_quote_submit_after', array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quote));
    $this->_order = $order;
    return $order;
```

Comment: The sales_model_service_quote_submit_before event has not hit before the order save, i have to convert the value from quote to order for that i tried the above event, I also tried sales_order_place_after,sales_convert_quote_to_order,
sales_model_service_quote_submit_success but non-of them worked

Comment: Thanks for the information @renon